# disable vimeo play pause button in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, vimeo

I have embedded a webview in my project where I am playing my vimeo player.When I start my project the player starts automatically .Till now everything is fine.Now ,I want to disable the controls that appear in the player.I am using `froogaloop.js` to embed the video.Is this possible ?If so,How can I do it.Coz in the vimeo api documentation there's isn't written anything about disabling the control.Please let me know if you need to review the code.